# how to replace for loop with function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, nested, sapply

I would like to replace the loops in the following code.

```
    Test<-function(j){
      card<-5
      #matrix s is to hold the results
      s <- matrix(rep(0,j*card),nrow=j,ncol=card,byrow=TRUE)

       # Loop1
       for (k in 1:j)
       { 
        #A vector should be drawn from another matrix, 
        #for simplicity, I define a vector "sol" to be modified in Loop2
        sol<-rep(1,card)
        #Given the vector "sol", select a vector position randomly 
        #for a given no. of times (i.e. steps), say 10.
        step<-10

            # Loop2 - Modify value in sol  
            for (i in seq_len(step))
            {
             #Draw a position
             r<-sample(seq_len(card),1)
             #Each position has specific probabilities for 
             #assignment of possible values, meaning p is related to
             #the position. 
             #For simplicity, just define the probabilities by random here.
             p<-runif(3,0,1)   # just create p for each step
             p<-p/sum(p)       #
             #Finally, draw a value for the selected position and
             #value of sol within this loop is kept changing.
             sol[r]<-sample(1:3,1,prob=p)
             }
        # keep the result in matrix s.
        s[k,]<-sol }
    return(s)}
```

Given an input vector

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

It is expected to output a matrix like this:

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    [1,]    1    1    3    2    3
    [2,]    1    1    1    1    3
    [3,]    2    2    2    2    3
    [4,]    2    1    2    2    1
    [5,]    1    1    3    1    1
```

Each step in Loop2 depends on a probability vector, which is then used to change value in the sol. Then I tried to replace Loop2 with sapply as follows:

```
    sapply(seq_len(steps), function(x){ 
      r<-runif(seq_len(card),1)
      sol[r]<-sample(1:3,1,prob=p) #Try to modify value in sol
     })
    s[k,]<-sol #Actually, no change in sol.
```

However, values in sol has no changed keeping all 1s, i.e. 1,1,1,1,1.

How can Loop2 be replaced by other apply family or other functions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, you don't need apply() functions for this:

```
Test <- function(j) {
  card <- 5

  p<-runif(3,0,1)
  p<-p/sum(p)

  out <- matrix(sample(1:3, j*card, replace=T, prob=p), ncol=card, nrow=j)
  return(out)
}

Test(5)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    2    1    1
[2,]    1    2    3    2    2
[3,]    2    3    1    1    2
[4,]    1    2    1    2    1
[5,]    2    1    1    2    2
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. In fact, p is changing in each step, so just use sample function is not okay. Sorry for confusion, and I've modified the question to reflect this.

Comment: I've added a new answer below though I'm not sure what the use of 'step' is. Maybe you could add a little more context so we now more precisely what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Benoit, thanks. I have added more comments in the code. Actually, I try to implement a gibbs sampling, or are there any generic r package can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

In order to refactor this function, notice that all the `r <- sample(card,1)` are independent draws from the multinomial distribution. This can be pulled out of the loop.

The second thing to note is that the conditional distribution of `s[i,j]` given `r` is 1 if the multinomial draw is zero, otherwise it is `sample(3,1,prob=runif(3))`. (The distribution does not change if a cell is selected repeatedly).

Put those two facts together, and we have this:

```
Test2 <- function(j,card=5,step=10) {

  r <- t(rmultinom(j,step,rep(1,card)))
  s <- apply(r, 1:2, function(x) if(x > 0) sample(3,1,prob=runif(3)) else 1)

  return(s)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about that:

```
test2 <- function(j) {

  card <- 5

  # Create a matrix where each of the j*card row is a p as defined in your original function.
  p <- matrix(runif(3*j*card), ncol=3)
  p <- t(apply(p, 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))

  # For each row of p, draw a single value at random
  draws <- apply(p, 1, function(x) sample(1:3, 1, prob=x))

  # Format the output as a j*card matrix
  out <- matrix(draws, ncol=card, byrow=TRUE)
  return(out)
}
```

If `test2()` does what you want, it's roughly 300 times faster than `Test()` on my machine.